# How do i get information from textview?

Tags: android, textview

Ii am trying to figure out how to get the information that a user entered into a textview box which contains userpassword and username. My goal is to display the information from the two fields when the user clicks the button Login. I am stuck trying to display the information.

```
  public class Login {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
     TextView usernameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userloginname);
     TextView passwordTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userpassword);

    TextView neighbourView = new TextView(this);
    neighbourView.setTag(usernameTextView);
    neighbourView.setTag(passwordTextView);

    Button button_test;
    button_test = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    button_test.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            String username = usernameTextView.toString();
            String password = passwordTextView.toString();
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "password is :" + password +"  " + username + "  ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // System.out.println(username + "" + password);
            Log.i(username + username, password + password);
        }
    });
    // return false;
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
  }
```

And my XML

```
     <!--  Username Label -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#372c24"
        android:text="@string/username"/>
    <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:id="@+id/userloginname"
        android:inputType="text" />
    <!--  Password Label -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#372c24"
        android:text="@string/password"/>
    <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:password="true"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:id="@+id/userpassword" />
    <!-- Login button -->
    <Button android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="@string/loginButton"/>
```

Comment: Try usernameTextView.getText().toString();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a user can't enter text on a TextView. You'll need an EditText for that. You already have EditText in your layout file, so initialize them like so

```
 EditText usernameEditText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userloginname);
 EditText passwordEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userpassword);
```

Then inside your onClick() method

```
public void onClick(View v) {

        String username = usernameEditText.getText().toString();
        String password = passwordEditText.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "password is :" + password +"  " + username + "  ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // System.out.println(username + "" + password);
        Log.i(username + username, password + password);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`usernameTextView`  and `passwordTextView`  are EditText not TextView.

Try to use

```
String username = usernameTextView.getText().toString();

String password = passwordTextView.getText().toString();
```

Instead of

```
String username = usernameTextView.toString();

String password = passwordTextView.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are converting the TextView to string which is wrong

`String username = usernameTextView.toString();`

Use this syntax instead of the above to get the text from Textview and converting it to string

`String username = usernameTextView.getText().toString();`